# Will limitting refreshes of a login-page in a period of time, protect the site from attacks?

Tags: php, security

My question is if you limit the refreshes let's say 30 to a period of 10 sec, will this prevent DDOS, flood, brute force attacks in the login or other page?

Comment: @Dani I don't know but anything can happen

Comment: I mean how will you implement this? the implementation must take time, which will be enough for a DDOS to clog up your system.

Comment: @Dani any action should be made before launching it. Sorry, I think I didn't get what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed Denial of Service, being by nature decentralized, would not all come from a single client, as such you would not be able to limit the entire botnet's access to the page... While it would help reduce the effect of each singular drone, it would not necessarily prevent them from hitting your server repeatedly.

However, in the case of a singular attacker, it would massively increase the time for a brute attack, but could be less pain to the user by implementing a three-strikes before delay rule or similar.

Comment: So I guess I should go with a "failed logins" column

Comment: Yes, I would also recommend storing the time they last tried to log in, and checking whether the difference was less than your delay, if so, add it to the counter; otherwise, set the counter to one on failure or clear it to 0 if their log in is successful.

Comment: Ok good with this but... I need to store the failed login number into a session for him. Otherwise he will be able to try to login every time and then get the e.g. captcha. Is that right ?

Comment: A session would allow you to store both failed login attempts as well as the time since the last attempt, so that may be the best course of action, yes.